# Emberjs resolver, amd and non-amd modules

Tags: javascript, ember.js, amd

I'm trying to use alertify with Emberjs. Thats how it is exported.

```
// AMD and window support
if (typeof define === "function") {
    define([], function () { return new Alertify(); });
} else if (typeof global.alertify === "undefined") {
    global.alertify = new Alertify();
}
```

I have put this line to Brocfile.js

```
app.import('./bower_components/alertify.js/lib/alertify.js');
```

But it thinks that it is AMD and to sum up I cant use it.

How should I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is Ember does not work with unnamed AMD modules.